# Создание многофункциональной и правильной навигации в приложении

Tags: java, material-design, android-navigation-drawer, bottom-navigation-view

Я создал в приложении простой Navigation Drawer со всеми фрагментами(шторка слева) и Bottom Navigation View, в который помещаются пять наиболее используемых фрагментов из простого Navigation Drawer. Правильно ли так делать?. Или можно что-то заменить?. Просто хочется, чтобы некоторые фрагменты из Navigation Drawer были в быстром доступе. Фото просто для примера.

Вот шторка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот Bottom Navigation View, где должны располагаться 5 наиболее используемых фрагментов (внизу)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]